# curious DHE implementation for key exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman

I have made some reverse engineering on proprietary software and came up with some DHE algorithm that works like this:

First and foremost, the client and the server shares some public parameters (g, p) where p is a prime number :

```
# the client generates some random number X
# Then...
A = g^X % p
B = 4^X % p
```

At this stade, A and B are two numbers computed with some exponentioation modulus p.

The client keeps A for itself and sends B over network to the server.

I can't guess out what's the server doing with B.

What comes up next is that the server sends the client back some buffer which is 20 bytes long. This buffer is **xored** with the first 20 bytes of the little-endian representation of A. Meaning something like this:

```
key = buffer ^ A[0...20]
```

And there you go, **key** is the shared key between the client and the server.

I am trying to guess out how the server generated that xoring buffer, and what did it compute with 'B'. Any clue?

**Edit:**

For instance, I have these numbers:

g=4251748925932087506992136911681457196421197968417424634771122535345596546655443876920558972863202693157925206950493858768680434551750613271334944372387511

p=7552255105811443149655814117645061441469802313473420161620729142606560015854445500056007762660457578016660416343667268412286196867181440500178902692672641

X (random number) = 8788592173807205653697600075440308493757969005221433286958441247128089107594429784362875543428031794230308326680487467902465260209524609291268858491985100

**How could  the server compute A?**

Comment: Is that a typo in B? Is it really $4$ instead of $g$?

Comment: 20 bytes is 160 bits, which could be SHA-1. You could try sending specific values to the server, and see if it is just a SHA-1 hash of the data you send it. I don't see how a shared key is even possible unless the server knows $X$, which it doesn't appear to.

Comment: @mikeazo it's not a typo in B and it is both g and 4.
Though It would be SHA-1, how the server would even know the value of A?

Comment: It can't (unless p is really small).

Comment: p is 512 bits long

Comment: How large is $X$?

Comment: 512 bits as well. They're all that long but the buffer (20 bytes long).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked, is $p$ a safe prime and/or is 4 a generator over $p$?

Server has random secret $S$, known $p$ and $g$ a generator.  I'm substituting in $V$ for your $g$, with $g = 4$.

$V = g^S \mod p$

$V$ is a verifier of the server, as in SRP.

$V$ is your $g$, so known by the client.  Anyone knowing $V$ can establish communications with the server.

You calculate for random $X$

$A = V^X \mod p$
$B = g^X \mod p$

So, when you send $B$, server calculates

$A = B^S = g^{XS} = V^X \mod p$

This is one-way authentication, of the server only.  You could do the same thing with the client, and have a mutually authenticated DH key exchange (each client would need a secret as well, and the server would have to know the corresponding verifier).

What's curious is why bother sending back anything, why not just use $A$ directly (or a hash of it, for example)?  If the 20-byte value isn't checked against anything else, it seems sort of useless.  It could be used as a proof, e.g. hash of $A$, but you don't indicate that it's used for anything except to XOR it with $A$.  Since it's being sent in the clear, it doesn't really add anything to the security.

Comment: Your answer makes sense! For your last paragraph, my guess is that the server sends some buffer back to actually both acknowledge the client's $B$ and to obfuscate a little bit more the key generation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your understanding the protocol correctly, the only way this can work is if the server is figuring out $X$ and using that to compute $A$. With $p$ being only 512 bits, it is possible to compute $X$, given $B$. But it would still take a fairly long time to do that, so I'm guessing that is not what the server is doing.

So, I'm guessing your understanding of the protocol is incorrect.

Comment: Well, ... if $p$ is constant, this would enable Logjam-style attacks meaning one could recover $X$ in 90s on consumer machines...

Comment: @sejpm good point

Comment: Maybe my understanding is incorrect; I get a correct shared key with the server though.

Comment: @SEJPM Assuming the precomputation for that $p$ is available.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of $p$? What is the value of $g$?

If $g = 2$, when he receives $4^X$, he could compute the square root of it so that he has $2^X$ which is your $A$.

Comment: p is a large 512 bits prime number and g is a large 512 random number. There value are shared between the client and the server.

Comment: My guess is g is some power of 4, so the server knows g = 4^y, so when he receives your B = 4^x, he computes B^y to get (4^x)^y = (4^y)^x= g^x, which is the client's A.

Comment: you might be right, I didn't check that g and p would be "bound" (don't know how do you say it) but I'll tell you what.

Comment: I mean, g and 4 would be bound*, not p and g (since p is definitely a prime number).

Comment: user13741: I have edited my question to provide readers with numbers. As one can see, g isn't a power of 4. Can you still help me though?

Comment: How do you know, that it is not a power of $4$? There is no other way for this to work, unless the server knows the logarithm of $g$ to base $4$. Essentially, this is just DH with the server's side always being static (similar to the public key in ElGamal). The generator used is actually $4$, and what is usually denoted $g^a$ in DH is called $g$ here.